# solving equation containing chi-square probability

Tags: matlab, equation, chi-squared

I want to solve this equation and find 'u' in Matlab.

[image: equation]

for the left side of this equation, we have `chi2cdf(u, 2*Nr, 'upper')`
but i can't use this and got an error.

```matlab
syms x positive

eqn = chi2cdf (x,2,'upper');
```

and i got this error:

```
Error using symengine

cannot prove 'x<0' literally. to test the statement mathematically, use isAlways.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to solve for u numerically given L and M or are you trying to solve this symbolically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use **function handle** instead, the ***sign*** of `x` matter only when evaluating the
  function
- When evaluating just set the range to `[0, inf]`, ***sign*** implicitly setted to **positive**
- Use `fzero()` to solve equation equal to zero
- `fzero()` doesn't allow infinite bound, `inf` could be replaced by `exp(709)`

> - Why `exp(709)`?: `exp(709) = finite` while `exp(710) = infinite`

**Code is as follows**

```
% Assuming L, M
L = 0.1;
M = 2;

% Equation
f =@(x) chi2cdf (x,2,'upper')-L/M;

% solve 
sol = fzero(f, [0, exp(709)]);
```

**Solution**

```
sol = 5.9915
```